# IntelliJ on Mac is saying that the file should be named Scratch.java but it already is

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, processing

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCSqA.png)

One of my students is using processing in IntelliJ on a Mac. We set it up using the same steps I used on my PC (Works on my PC), but now it gives me an error stating that the filename should be Scratch.java, but it already is (see attached photo).

What could be causing this? We tried a computer restart and we're getting the same error still.

Comment: Invalidate cache & restart IDEA

Answer (score 1):

## IntelliJ’s *Scratches* feature

You need to remove `public` from your class definition.

From: `public class Scratch extends PApplet`
To: `class Scratch extends PApplet`

It seems that is because the file is located under the *Scratches and Consoles* dir.
More info about intelliJ's scratch [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html). 
If you place it under the *src* directory, it can be public.

Comment: `public` is required in order to run the classes `main()` method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Are you sure? That is not usually a requirement.

Comment: Without it being public you get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class processing.core.PApplet can not access a member of class Scratch with modifiers

Also the same code works fine on a Windows Machine. Does OSX set us scratches differently from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried rewriting the class name and renaming the file again, perhaps a charset encoding problem ? Or like LppEdd says cleaning cache and restarting IDEA, hope it helps